# Laravel 5 Migration, Invalid default value when integer

Tags: php, migration, schema, laravel-5, builder

I was trying to create an table having a **0** as its default integer value
The code looks like:

```
Schema::create('gsd_proyecto', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nombre', 80)->unique();
        $table->string('descripcion', 250)->nullable();
        $table->date('fechaInicio')->nullable();
        $table->date('fechaFin')->nullable();
        $table->integer('estado', 1)->default(0);
        $table->string('ultimoModifico', 35)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

But when I run the migration I'm getting the next error:

```
Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'estado'
```

I was checking what is the SQL created by laravel and I found next

```
create table `gsd_proyecto` (
 `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
 `nombre` varchar(80) not null, 
 `descripcion` varchar(250) null, 
 `fechaInicio` date null, 
 `fechaFin` date null, 
 `estado` int not null default '0' auto_increment primary key,   
 `ultimoModifico` varchar(35) null, 
 `created_at` timestamp default 0 not null, 
 `updated_at` timestamp default 0 not null
)
```

As you can see, laravel is trying to set the field **estado** with a char value (**'0'**) and also as an autoincrement primary key

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove the second parameter in the `integer` method. It sets the column as auto-increment. Check the Laravel API for more detials.

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_integer

```
$table->integer('estado')->default(0);
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks A lot! I was thinking in a definition like MySql does....instead I'm using tinyInteger now and it's working now. Thanks a lot!